# Why does Amplify Datastore return null in objects having @hasmany relationships?

Tags: flutter, datastore, aws-amplify

I'm new here and I hope to find a solution to this problem. I am new to Flutter and AWS Amplify as well. Here it goes.

I created a very simple schema using Admin UI. The schema has two models, Order and Item. Order contains many Item(s).

I was surprised that call to get OrderItems() returns null. I read a post elsewhere that said @hasmany relationships do not work with with AWS Amplify and a second query was needed to retrieve @hasmany fields.

The CLI generated models seem to support @hasmany relationships.

Here is the simple schema generated by Amplify:

```
type Items @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  productName: String
  quantity: String
  orderID: ID @index(name: "byOrder")
}

type Order @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  Customer: String
  OrderItems: [Items] @hasMany(indexName: "byOrder", fields: ["id"])
}
```

Amplify generated the corresponding models in my project. For brevity, I will include selected parts of the CLI generated code for the Order object. I don't believe the generated models can be modified. Moreover, If the schema is changed, the model dart project files are overwritten.

```
  @override
  String getId() {
    return id;
  }
  
  String? get Customer {
    return _Customer;
  }
// Returns null 
List<Items>? get OrderItems {
    return _OrderItems;
  }
```

It appears that ['OrderItems'] should be populate in Order.fromJson.

```
  Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)  
    : id = json['id'],
      _Customer = json['Customer'],
      _OrderItems = json['OrderItems'] is List
        ? (json['OrderItems'] as List)
          .where((e) => e?['serializedData'] != null)
          .map((e) => Items.fromJson(new Map<String, dynamic>.from(e['serializedData'])))
          .toList()
        : null;
```

What am I missing? What is the purpose of this code?

The remainder of the CLI generated code seems to support CRUD operations on both Order and Item.

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'id': id, 'Customer': _Customer, 'OrderItems': _OrderItems?.map((Items? e) => e?.toJson()).toList()
  };

  static final QueryField ID = QueryField(fieldName: "order.id");
  static final QueryField CUSTOMER = QueryField(fieldName: "Customer");
  static final QueryField ORDERITEMS = QueryField(
    fieldName: "OrderItems",
    fieldType: ModelFieldType(ModelFieldTypeEnum.model, ofModelName: (Items).toString()));
  static var schema = Model.defineSchema(define: (ModelSchemaDefinition modelSchemaDefinition) {
    modelSchemaDefinition.name = "Order";
    modelSchemaDefinition.pluralName = "Orders";
    
    modelSchemaDefinition.authRules = [
      AuthRule(
        authStrategy: AuthStrategy.PUBLIC,
        operations: [
          ModelOperation.CREATE,
          ModelOperation.UPDATE,
          ModelOperation.DELETE,
          ModelOperation.READ
        ])
    ];
    
    modelSchemaDefinition.addField(ModelFieldDefinition.id());
    
    modelSchemaDefinition.addField(ModelFieldDefinition.field(
      key: Order.CUSTOMER,
      isRequired: false,
      ofType: ModelFieldType(ModelFieldTypeEnum.string)
    ));
    
    modelSchemaDefinition.addField(ModelFieldDefinition.hasMany(
      key: Order.ORDERITEMS,
      isRequired: false,
      ofModelName: (Items).toString(),
      associatedKey: Items.ORDERID
    ));
  });
}

class _OrderModelType extends ModelType<Order> {
  const _OrderModelType();
  
  @override
  Order fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return Order.fromJson(jsonData);
  }
}
```

It appears that all the plumbing is in place but the water is turned off. Like I stated, I'm new at this so...

Is this a bug?

One last thing...

ModelProvider.dart throw this compile time error.

```
Missing concrete implementations of 'getter ModelProviderInterface.customTypeSchemas' and 'setter ModelProviderInterface.customTypeSchemas'.
Try implementing the missing methods, or make the class abstract
```

Whenever ModelProvider.dart is regenerated I have to add the following line of code.

```
  @override
  List<ModelSchema> customTypeSchemas =[];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Im getting the same error, we should add this as an issue to the github repository

Comment: have you found a solution? I am experiencing the same problem. Im confused why @hasMany is a configuration option if it doesnt work .

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, @hasOne and @hasMany directives do not support referencing a model which then references the initial model via @hasOne or @hasMany if DataStore is enabled.

Details: [Has-One-Relationship](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-one-relationship)